# Macro: Insert a new row above a cell containing a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a column containing the following values:
A1 = 0
A2 = 1
A3 = 3
A4 = 4
A5 = 0 
A6 = 1

I wish to select column A and insert a new column above any instance of 0.

I have tried the following code but I am getting errors and not sure what is wrong. I believe it is OFFSET that is causing the problem, I'm not 100% sure.

```
Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Range("A:A")
    If c.Value Like "0" Then
      c.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
  Next c
```

It says the following:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or
>   object-defined error.

Then it highlights `c.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert` in the code

Comment: How about showing us the errors you get?

Comment: I tried posting a screen shot but I don't have enough reputation to do so. It says the following: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Then it highlights "c.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert" in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cell at `Range("A1").offset(-1)`, so it fails as the object does not exist. Change `A1` to something else and it will work otherwise.

This is probably what you want to do -

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Range("A:A")
    If c.Value Like "0" Then
      Rows(c.Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
  Next c
End Sub
```

But, you'll be stuck in an infinite loop with just this code. You should have something like this instead -

```
Sub test()
Dim d As Integer
d = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
Dim c As Range
  For i = d To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value Like "0" Then
      Rows(Cells(i, 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```